# Xcode: Different image sizes for different resolutions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image

We use a lot of pictures in our app and I am just wondering: If I need a 24x24 picture and I need the x1, x2 and x3 size -> can't I just use 72x72 for all of them and Xcode/iOS does the resizing magic itself? The pictures aren't too big so I guess this could simplify our work?

Comment: yes. but sometimes the results are ugly. you have to try and see.

Comment: Use pdf instead of images and try to use single scale.